# How old is the Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavad-gita

I know it was spoken in the battlefield of Mahabharata by Lord Krishna. If Lord Krishna departed around 3102 B.C (the beginning of Kali), the events of the Mahabharata must have occurred before it. If someone could trace back the events and give me an estimate on when the Bhagavad Gita was spoken, it would be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When did the Mahabharata war take place?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21493/277)