# How old is the Mahabharata manuscript?

Tags: mahabharata, history, manuscripts

Many people say that the Mahabharata is from 5000 B.C

How old is the Mahabharata? Is there any proof that Mahabharata is as old as 5000 B.C?

Is the Mahabharata manuscript written by Ganapati available now or did it burn in Nalanda University?

According to the Puranas and epics what happened to those paramparas of students to whom Vyasa had given Mahabharata to protect?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When did the Mahabharata war take place?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21493/when-did-the-mahabharata-war-take-place)

Comment: I am talking of Manu scripture

Comment: What do you mean by "Mahabharata Manu scripture?" You mean how old is the oldest extant Mahabharata manuscript?

Comment: Yes I mean that only